# canvas.getContext() is not a function

Tags: javascript, canvas

Currently am doing research on how to interate Coldfusion with Canvas. At the moment, i'm stuck due to javascript error "canvas.getContext('2d'); is not a function".

The canvas has to be located inside a div:

```
<div id="svgbasics" name="svgbasics"></div>
```

This is the javascript used to generate the image

```
var canvas = $('#svgbasics').svg('get').toSVG();
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var strDataURI = canvas.toDataURL();
Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
```

---

Project's additional info (if needed):

- the following libraries are used: `1.7.2/jquery.min.js`, `jquery.svg.js`, `base64.js` and `canvas2image.js`
- `$('#svgbasics').svg('get').toSVG();` returns something like this:

  `<svg xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg"; version="1.1" width="400" height="300"><circle cx="75" cy="75" r="50" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3"/><g stroke="black" stroke-width="2"><line x1="15" y1="75" x2="135" y2="75"/><line x1="75" y1="15" x2="75" y2="135"/></g></svg>`

Comment: .svg('get').toSVG(); ? if that thing doesnt return a canvas element you cant get no context.

Comment: Please post the entire contents of the svgbasics div.

Comment: Sorry am extremely new with this.

In this case, it returns something like this:
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="400" height="300"><circle cx="75" cy="75" r="50" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3"/><g stroke="black" stroke-width="2"><line x1="15" y1="75" x2="135" y2="75"/><line x1="75" y1="15" x2="75" y2="135"/></g></svg>

Comment: @adrian Please update your question with that, it's difficult to read in comments.

Comment: SVG and Canvas are two different things (for one thing SVG does not have `getContext()`). This will give you some more info on the subject: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp

Answer (score 31):

You should refer to `<canvas .....> </canvas>`  element, not `<div>` or etc !

Answer (score 16):

Try:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasEl");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Where `canvasEl` is a `<canvas id="canvasEl"></canvas>`. Your `$('#svgbasics').svg('get').toSVG();` probably doesn't return an HTML canvas element which it must for the `.getContext('2d')` to exist.

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing SVG canvas with the new HTML5 Canvas.

They are different animals.  Please take a look at this article for the differences between Canvas and SVG (there is a "Differences between Canvas and SVG" section): http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp

From your script tags, I can see you are using jQuery SVG:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.svg.js"></script>
```

This page shows an example of using getting and manipulating the SVG Canvas: http://keith-wood.name/svg.html.

Comment: hmm.. thanks guys. I'll need to reconsider on my options

May request for your opinions on this.

The project basically allows users to select areas on an image that'd like to put a marker.

For example, a map will be loaded on to the screen and wherever any user touches or click on the map, there will be a marker automatically created on the spot. Something like "X marks the spot". The system will then save the marked map as an image and upload into the server for storing

Any opinion on what should i use or try for this project?